# Spatial MySQL with Entity Framework

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, geospatial

Is this possible now to use Spatial with MySql and Entity Framework? Couldn't find blog nor document nor help about that. Any direction is appreciated.

Comment: I guess no unless there is MySQL provider for EF 4.5 / 5.0.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of yet, but seeing how [Devart recently released support for Migrations](http://www.devart.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=23262), I'd expect them to follow up with spaital support pretty soon too.